# How can I set global Sass variables in Vue with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, sass-loader

These are the versions of Sass modules I use:

```
node-sass@^4

sass-loader@^7
```

I tried to set a global Sass variable in `vue.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `$primaryColor: #16A085;`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But after running `npm run dev`, I get following error:

```
Module build failed:
     color: $primaryColor;
           ^
      Undefined variable: "$primaryColor".
      in C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\projekty\projectsBacketlist\noteTakingApp\frontend\noteTakkingApp\src\views\NoteEdit.vue (line 157, column 13)

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-b5e02554","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/views/NoteEdit.vue 4:14-374 13:3-17:5 14:22-382
 @ ./src/views/NoteEdit.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [project](https://github.com/TomekPulkiewicz/NoteTakingAppFrontend) is not a [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) generated project, so `vue.config.js` would not be processed at all.

In your case, you'd configure the Sass 7.x loaders in [`build/utils.js`](https://github.com/TomekPulkiewicz/NoteTakingAppFrontend/blob/8ebc353/build/utils.js#L62-L63) to pass the [`data`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/tree/v7.1.0#environment-variables) option:

```js
exports.cssLoaders = function (options) {
  //...

  return {
    //...
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { data: `$primaryColor: #16A085;` }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass', { data: `$primaryColor: #16A085;` }),
  }
}
```

However, you should be aware of the note from the `sass-loader` docs:

> **Please note:** Since you're injecting code, this will break the source mappings in your entry file. Often there's a simpler solution than this, like multiple Sass entry files.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and this is my solution:

```
      return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    // scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass', { data: `@import '@/scss/_variables.scss';` }),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
}
```

My file was in "src" so basically go to top and find folder scss.